# How would i turn this function into a class?

Tags: python, class, zelle-graphics

I want to turn this code into a class where I can make other rectangles using the same class but just switching things around.

```
def appBox(win1):
    appBox=Rectangle(Point(4,15), Point(11,13))
    appBox.setOutline("darkorange2")
    appBox.setFill("white")
    appLabel=Text(Point(7.5,14),"Beats By Cuse")
    appLabel.setSize(35)
    appLabel.setFace("courier")
    appLabel.setStyle("bold italic")
    appLabel.setFill("darkorange2")
    appBox.draw(win1)
    appLabel.draw(win1)
    return appBox, appLabel
```

Comment: Classes carry state. What state do you want the class to carry?

Comment: I guess the def __init__() if that would work. -Silvio Mayolo

Comment: What I mean to say is, the reason to *have* a class is to have some sort of mutable state encapsulated. Sure, you can take this function and wrap it in an incredibly pointless class that does nothing, but that's not good programming; that's just silly. If there's a good reason to wrap it in a class, then we can help you with that, but based on what you've shown us your function seems fine as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you asking how do I pass parameters to this function so that I can change outputs dynamically?

```
def function(arg1=1.0,arg2=1.0,arg3=1.0):
    return arg1 * arg2 * arg3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough example of turning this into a class to let you pump out lots of these boxed texts.  In this case, the new `AppBox` class *is* a subclass of `Rectangle` that *contains* a `Label`:

```
from graphics import *

class AppBox(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, text):
        super().__init__(p1, p2)

        self.text = text
        self.setOutline("darkorange2")
        self.setFill("white")

        midpoint = Point((p1.getX() + p2.getX()) / 2, (p1.getY() + p2.getY()) / 2)

        self.label = Text(midpoint, self.text)
        self.label.setSize(18)
        self.label.setFace("courier")
        self.label.setStyle("bold italic")
        self.label.setFill("darkorange2")

    def draw(self, graphwin):
        super().draw(graphwin)
        self.label.draw(graphwin)

beats = AppBox(Point(15, 15), Point(185, 35), "Beats By Cuse")

jeans = AppBox(Point(200, 60), Point(365, 80), "Jeans By Levi")

win = GraphWin(width=450, height=225)

beats.draw(win)
jeans.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

A better implementation might be to supply the `AppBox` constructor just one (center) point and have it compute the rectangle points based on the text length, font size, etc.

[image]